# Set addresses in a function from root in PHP

Tags: php, directory, root

I’m working on a script on `localhost` using a WAMP server. I wanted to make my website multilingual so I defined a function which you can see below:

```
function p($name,$langIn = 'fa_IR')
{
    switch ($langIn) {
        case 'en_US':
            require('/inc/languages/en_US/all_lang_en_US.php');
        break;
        default:
            require('/inc/languages/fa_IR/all_lang_fa_IR.php');
    }

    if(isset($lang[$name]))
        echo $lang[$name];
    else
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Error!</span>';
}
```

The function stored in `localhost/aroozi/inc/functions/global_func.php`. The required address works properly on `localhost/aroozi` but when I post the registration form values to `localhost/aroozi/processors/register.php` it doesn't work and the script will stopped working because I used `p()` function in the header of pages in `localhost/aroozi/inc/header.php`:

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
.
.
.
<title><?php p('title',$lang); ?></title>
.
.
.
```

My basic question is how can I set an address so that works in all of the directories of the script?

Comment: `function p()` shouldn't output the text by itself. Instead it should return it.

`function p() { ... return $lang[$name]; ... }`

And in your HTML file you should use `<title><?=p('title', $lang); ?></title>` instead.

Comment: Whats's the difference? it works carefully now in root directory and it doesnt need `echo` command. Also i was test your solution, Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. However, The important thing is that I want to fix the problem at first. After that I will think about that issue. Thanks.

Comment: Of course! I'm trying your solution via different scenarios.

Comment: @JakeGould Looks like I missunderstood the question then. For me it sounds like he was getting an `Headers already sent` error message from PHP because of using `echo` inside the `p()` function. However I would design the function in that way I suggested because separating processing from output is a cleaner paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My basic question is how can I set an address so that works in all of
>   the directories of the script?

The issue is you are relying on relative paths—like `require('/inc/languages/…)`—which is not good practice. You can go nuts trying to balance where to set `/` or `../` or even `../../`. And the best way to avoid it is to set a base path in your main config.

So you would set something like this in a config file:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/full/path/to/your/codebase/here/';
```

If you don’t know what your file system base path is, just place this line of code in your PHP code; like `index.php`:

```
echo "Your path is: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "<br />";
```

Then load that page. Somewhere near the top will be this text:

> Your path is: /full/path/to/your/codebase/here/

Then with that set you can change your code to be something like this:

```
include_once 'config.php';

function p($name,$langIn = 'fa_IR')
{
    global $BASE_PATH;

    switch ($langIn) {
        case 'en_US':
            require_once($BASE_PATH . 'inc/languages/en_US/all_lang_en_US.php');
        break;
        default:
            require_once($BASE_PATH . 'inc/languages/fa_IR/all_lang_fa_IR.php');
    }

    if(isset($lang[$name]))
        echo $lang[$name];
    else
        echo '<span style="color: red;">Error!</span>';
}
```

Note the changes I made are as follows:

- Setting `include_once` for the `config.php` for this example. Place it wherever makes sense in your code.
- Setting `global $BASE_PATH;` within the function so that `$BASE_PATH` can easily be loaded in the function.
- Changing the`require` calls to `require_once` since it is just better practice & helps the code avoid situations where multiple `require` calls might cause your script to bomb out.
- Setting `$BASE_PATH . 'inc/languages/` in the `require_once` calls to actually use the `$BASE_PATH` concept.

Yes, it seems like more work to setup a `config.php` that is loaded via a relative path and then using `$BASE_PATH` on the next line, but the benefit is that once those `config.php` lines are set, you no longer have to worry about it.  Then `$BASE_PATH` can be set to meet the needs of whatever setup you are on.

**EDIT:** As per the comments, the original poster is not understanding the difference between a file system path & a web server URL. To be as clear as possible, this is the file system path as reported by the original poster in Windows:

```
C:\wamp\www\aroozi
```

And this is the web URL that accesses that WAMP URL via a web browser:

```
http://localhost/aroozi
```

When a request is made to the files for `http://localhost/aroozi` the web server looks inside `C:\wamp\www\aroozi` on the file system.  So that path is consider the base path on the file system.

So using my example above this would be set as follows for Apache PHP use; Windows paths have he slashes reversed since PHP & Apache in WAMP work via Unix/Linux path setups:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/wamp/www/aroozi';
```

Or using the original posters config setup in `constants.php`:

define('BASE_PATH','/wamp/www/aroozi');

And then just prepend either `$BASE_PATH` or `BASE_PATH` to the `require`/`include` suff like this:

```
require_once($BASE_PATH . 'inc/languages/en_US/all_lang_en_US.php');
```

Or this:

```
require_once(BASE_PATH . 'inc/languages/en_US/all_lang_en_US.php');
```

Comment: But I've done it before. I have a config file in `localhost/aroozi/inc/constants.php` with this content: `define( 'ROOT' , '/aroozi' );`. I tested your idea but i didn't see any correct result:  `require(ROOT.'/inc/languages/fa_IR/all_lang_fa_IR.php');`. Even i changed `require` to `require_once`! (Excuse me for repost comment)

Comment: The function you said return `C:\wamp\www\aroozi`. It isn't a web url. doesn't it?

Comment: As far as I know we should use `/localHost/` instead `/wamp/www/`. So I should use `include` or `require` to use my constants?

Comment: Ok. Therefore I should use web urls for web files like stylesheets or ... and use file system paths for `require` php files or some other like it. that's right?